# Loop through all Word Files in Directory

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following code:

```
Sub WordtoTxtwLB()
'
' WordtoTxtwLB Macro
'
'
Dim fileName As String
myFileName = ActiveDocument.Name

ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 fileName:= _
"\\FILE\" & myFileName & ".txt", FileFormat:= _
wdFormatText, LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles:=True, _
WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, _
SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:= _
False, Encoding:=1252, InsertLineBreaks:=True, AllowSubstitutions:=False, _
LineEnding:=wdCRLF, CompatibilityMode:=0


End Sub
```

I want to loop this sub through all of the word (.doc) files in a directory. I have the following code:

```
Sub LoopDirectory()

vDirectory = "C:\programs2\test"

vFile = Dir(vDirectory & "\" & "*.*")

Do While vFile <> ""

Documents.Open fileName:=vDirectory & "\" & vFile

ActiveDocument.WordtoTxtwLB

vFile = Dir
Loop

End Sub
```

But it is not working.  How do I get this to work either by altering the current code or using new code?

Comment: `WordtoTxtwLB` isn't a method of ActiveDocument, so just use the method name by itself.  Better, adapt your method to take a parameter of type "Document" and pass the opened document to it directly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't actually need the WordtoTxtwLB Macro. You can combine both the codes. see this example

```
Sub LoopDirectory()
    Dim vDirectory As String
    Dim oDoc As Document
    
    vDirectory = "C:\programs2\test\"

    vFile = Dir(vDirectory & "*.*")

    Do While vFile <> ""
        Set oDoc = Documents.Open(fileName:=vDirectory & vFile)
        
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 fileName:="\\FILE\" & oDoc.Name & ".txt", _
                               FileFormat:=wdFormatText, _
                               LockComments:=False, _
                               Password:="", _
                               AddToRecentFiles:=True, _
                               WritePassword:="", _
                               ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
                               EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, _
                               SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, _
                               SaveFormsData:=False, _
                               SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, _
                               Encoding:=1252, _
                               InsertLineBreaks:=True, _
                               AllowSubstitutions:=False, _
                               LineEnding:=wdCRLF, _
                               CompatibilityMode:=0

        oDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
        vFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

BTW, are you sure you want to use the `*.*` wildcard? What if there are Autocad files in the folder? Also `ActiveDocument.Name` will give you the file name with the Extension.

Comment: How would I get this to only apply to .docm documents?

Comment: Replace `Dir(vDirectory & "*.*")` with `Dir(vDirectory & "*.docm")`

Answer (score 2):

To edit all the word documents in a directory I built this simple subroutine.

The subRoutine loops through the directory and
opens each *.doc file it finds. Then on the open document file it calls
the second subRoutine. After the second subRoutine is finished the document
is saved and then closed.

```
Sub DoVBRoutineNow()
Dim file
Dim path As String


path = "C:\Documents and Settings\userName\My Documents\myWorkFolder\"

file = Dir(path & "*.doc")
Do While file <> ""
Documents.Open FileName:=path & file

Call secondSubRoutine

ActiveDocument.Save
ActiveDocument.Close

file = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

~~~~~~

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. I think it's easy to understand and straight forward for newbies like me that I will post my code here. Because I searched around and the codes I saw were kind of complicated. Let's go.

```
Sub loopDocxs()
Dim wApp As Word.Application 
Dim wDoc As Word.Document 
Dim mySource As Object
Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set mySource = obj.GetFolder("D:\docxs\")

For Each file In mySource.Files 'loop through the directory
  If Len(file.Name) > 0 And InStr(1, file.Name, "$") = 0 Then '$ is temp file mask

    Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wApp.Visible = True
    'Word.Application doesn't recognize file here event if it's a word file.
    'fortunately we have the file name which we can use.
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(mySource & "\" & file.Name, , ReadOnly)

    'Do your things here which will be a lot of code

    wApp.Quit
    Set wApp = Nothing


  End If
Next file
```