# How can I batch this VBA code on a folder full of word documents?

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I have a piece of code to add a table of contents in a word file that worked well when used on one file. How can I extend this to a folder full of word documents. The word documents are already all in one folder.

I have tried to adapt the code from the answers to this stackoverflow question but it did not do anything - no error message but also no output at all ([Loop through all Word Files in Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526577/loop-through-all-word-files-in-directory)). Here is what I tried:

```
    Dim vDirectory As String
    Dim oDoc As Document

    vDirectory = "C:\programs2\test\"

    vFile = Dir(vDirectory & "*.*")

    Do While vFile <> ""
        Set oDoc = Documents.Open(fileName:=vDirectory & vFile)

        Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0) 
        ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents.Add _ 
         Range:=myRange, _ 
         UseFields:=False, _ 
         UseHeadingStyles:=True, _ 
         LowerHeadingLevel:=3, _ 
         UpperHeadingLevel:=1, _ 
         AddedStyles:="myStyle, yourStyle"

        oDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
        vFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Here is the code that worked on a single document:

```
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0) 
ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents.Add _ 
 Range:=myRange, _ 
 UseFields:=False, _ 
 UseHeadingStyles:=True, _ 
 LowerHeadingLevel:=3, _ 
 UpperHeadingLevel:=1, _ 
 AddedStyles:="myStyle, yourStyle"
```

The expected output is that every word file in the relevant folder has a table of contents automatically added at the beginning

Comment: Please share how you tried to adapt the code from the linked answer.

Comment: "it did not work for me" - it's exactly the type of code which someone might post here as an answer, so if it didn't work for you it's always useful to (a) show exactly what you tried and (b) explain what errors you got, or how it didn't produce the expected result.

Comment: BigBen, Tim Williams, thanks for the feedback. I edited my question to include the code that I tried.

Comment: `oDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False` don't you want to save the changes though?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using ActiveDocument when dealing with a bunch of files. Specify the document variable explicitly:

```
 Do While vFile <> ""
        Set oDoc = Documents.Open(fileName:=vDirectory & vFile)

        Set myRange = oDoc.Range(0, 0) 

        oDoc.TablesOfContents.Add _ 
         Range:=myRange, _ 
         UseFields:=False, _ 
         UseHeadingStyles:=True, _ 
         LowerHeadingLevel:=3, _ 
         UpperHeadingLevel:=1, _ 
         AddedStyles:="myStyle, yourStyle"

        oDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
        vFile = Dir
    Loop
```

Comment: Aiyuni, thanks for your answer. I tried it but I again don't see any output or error message.

Comment: In general, when dealing with code that gives no useful output or errors: Have you tried debugging through the code line by line and seeing what it is actually doing/changing, if anything?

Comment: Aiyuni, I have tried and, to the best of my understanding, each line of the code makes sense. I might just be too green at this point to figure out where the code is failing. I'll keep trying. Thank you for your help

Comment: Tim, I did change that to True and tried but still no luck. I isolated the code within the loop and checked it to see if I maybe screwed something up there but that worked fine on one document. The issue seems to be in the loop

Answer (score 0):

I modified this to use the following code and it worked perfectly:

```
Sub InsertTOC()
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim doc As Document
    With Application.FileDialog(4) ' msoFileDialogFolderPicker
        If .Show Then
            strPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "No folder specified!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        strPath = strPath & "\"
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.docx")
    Do While strFile <> ""
        Set doc = Documents.Open(strPath & strFile)
        Set myRange = doc.Range(0, 0) 
    doc.TablesOfContents.Add _ 
     Range:=myRange, _ 
     UseFields:=False, _ 
     UseHeadingStyles:=True, _ 
     LowerHeadingLevel:=3, _ 
     UpperHeadingLevel:=1, _ 
     AddedStyles:="myStyle, yourStyle"
        doc.Close SaveChanges:=True
        strFile = Dir
    Loop
ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```